# How to use flexbox with anchored columns

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, flexbox

I'm using `display:flex` in order to have same height of child's columns.

Everything works well when `col-...` is immediate child of `display:flex` parent:

```
<div class="container flex">

    <div class="col-sm-4 flex-col">
      jkkfjds<br>dsfjdk<br>fdsfk
    </div>



    <div class="col-sm-6 flex-col">
      jfkdjkfsdjk
    </div>
</div>

.flex {
  display:flex;
}

.flex-col {
  border:1px solid black;
}
```

However I want flex-col to be anchored. When I try to add `<a>` as a parent of `<div class="col-sm-4 flex-col">` it all breaks down like this:

http://www.bootply.com/C8SmhEmvGS

I've already tried setting `display:block` to `<a>` but it didn't help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `col-sm-4 flex-col` class to `a` instead of `div`.

```
<div class="container flex">
  <a href="#" class="col-sm-4 flex-col">
    <div >
      jkkfjds<br>dsfjdk<br>fdsfk
    </div>
  </a>

  <a href="#" class="col-sm-6 flex-col">
    <div >
      jfkdjkfsdjk
    </div>
  </a>
 </div>
```

**[Working bootply](http://www.bootply.com/YRjJVqKf8P)**